# SVG has an incorrect height in Safari

Tags: css, svg, safari

Inline SVG doesn't always seem to respect percentage-based sizes set on the `<svg>` element in Safari.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 80px;
  background-color: #fcc;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  fill: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

You can see it on CodePen: https://codepen.io/pavelp/pen/EEOjNQ

Chrome output:

[image]

Safari output:

[image]

There are ways to fix it, for instance, using pixel sizes for the `<svg>` element instead of percentages - but let’s say I need percentages.

It can also be fixed by wrapping the `<svg>` with an unstyled `<div>`: https://codepen.io/pavelp/pen/bvQVER

Questions:

- What is causing the issue? Is it a Safari bug (if so, does anyone know if there's an entry in their bugtracker?) or is it a gray area in the spec?
- Why does the extra wrapper fix the issue?
- Is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this too.

> What is causing the issue? Is it a Safari bug (if so, does anyone know
>   if there's an entry in their bugtracker?) or is it a gray area in the
>   spec?

Seems to be related to: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154049 .

> Why does the extra wrapper fix the issue?

The wrapper alone did, in fact, not solve the problem, setting the height of the wrapper to 100% did.
This is persumably because the bug is related to SVG elements, DIV elements behave as expected.

> Is there a cleaner solution?

My workaround was to add the padding to the SVG instead of the parent.
Not sure if it's cleaner, but swapping a line of CSS was easier than wrapping all affected elements in a DIV